# Multiple Kong Ingress Controller for KIC 3.0.x

Tags: kubernetes, api-gateway, kong, ingress-controller, kong-ingress

The latest Kong Ingress Controller just comes out and im trying to go about it. But I'm currently stuck with it because of the need to use multiple ingress controller. Though KIC 2.0.x has a documentation for multiple ingress controller, the 3.0.x does not have one. Is there anyone who can help me with it?

The expected result would be having 2 different ingress controller with 2 external ip addresses with the type of load balancer. Any other methods other than using multi KIC 3.0.x are also accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of splitting internal/external traffic at https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/custom-class/internal-external/

You need multiple ingress controllers + Kong Gateway deployments if you want to split traffic.

Comment: thank you for the answer Michael. I have already looked at the information that you provided before.  Just to follow up with the answer, do we need to create another gateway and gatewayclass for the extra ingress controller?

Comment: Yes, you need one gatewayclass for each distinct set of configuration that you want to manage.

Comment: Set gateway-api-controller-name to customise the gatewayclass that a controller reconciles. https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/reference/resource-requiring-ingress-class/#gateway-class